# My mesh isn't moving with the bones

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

I'm really new to blender and am trying to make a badger animation for my toddler (he loves badgers...)
I know I haven't made a brilliant model and that may be the issue, but I can't get the mesh to move with the bones. Have I rigged it incorrectly?
Thank you in advance for any help.

Mike

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

1. Apply all transformations to mesh and armature (select mesh/armature then CTRL+a)
2. Make the armature the parent of your Mesh. To do so in *Object Mode* select the badger mesh and then on the *Object* tab at the bottom there is a "Relations" menu. Open it and click on the "Parent" text box. Select the Armature object and set the option below to "Armature":
   [image]
3. Then select your Armature and go to *Pose Mode* and select a bone which you want to assign to faces (here the head bone):
   [image]
4. Then shift click on the badger mesh. With the mesh selected go to *Weight Paint* mode. Now you can assign faces to the done by "Painting" on the mesh. Assigned faces will become red:
   [image]
5. With the faces assigned you can now go back to *Pose Mode* of the armature and the faces should follow deformations of the bones. Note the "Pose Position" selected in the panel to the right:
   [image]

One advice: your mesh is very distorted and it will be hard to achieve something satisfying without some rework of the mesh. I did some cleanup, if you like I can share my edited mesh...

Comment: Thank you for the reply, much appreciated. It would be great to have a look at your edited mesh to see how I could improve it.

Comment: Hi Michael, I uploaded the edited mesh: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3960" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3960/)

Comment: Thanks again. Why, when I try putting the legs in different poses, do they stretch and deform?

Comment: Hi Michael, I guess this is because the mesh ist not overly optimized for moving get with the bones and because I didn't do the weight painting with too much care. To get to a mesh which is fit for an it action is an art of it's own.... And I'm not a master of that ;)